# Why is the *Delete* option grayed out for my package dependency in xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift-package

Xcode version: 15.2 (15C500b)

I've looked around in various screens in Xcode but have not seen any way to delete a package dependency. Some StackOverflow posts mention the screen option `Swift Packages` but I can't find it in Xcode either.

Below is a screenshot showing the `Delete` option being grayed out

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Delete menu item is disabled because a Package has a complex integration with your project and must be deintegrated in good order. To do so, click the project at the top of the project navigator to edit it. On the right, make sure the project is selected, not a target. Across the top, find the Package Dependencies tab. Click it. You will see a list of dependencies. Select your package and hit the Minus button.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that some packages may have simple integration, and for these, the Delete option would be accessible? How do I find out if a package has a complex or simple integration?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. I'm saying this is how to delete a package.

Comment: Understood. May I ask when the Delete option is applicable and active? If it's not applicable, should it not be visible to avoid confusion?

Comment: "May I ask when the Delete option is applicable and active? If it's not applicable, should it not be visible to avoid confusion?" No, that's not how Mac applications work. A menu item that isn't applicable to the current situation is conventionally _disabled,_ not removed. Delete is enabled in this menu if, for example, what you selected is a file of your own project in the Project navigator, such as your _main_.